# Rebuilding SVG sprites throws "Not allowed to override geometry on sprite"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I think I'm running into a form of race condition with Unity when I try to change `SpriteRenderer sprites`

Here is how I build GameObjects each has a nested game object to represent an icon

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    GameObject obj = new(data[i].Details.UID.ToString());
    obj.transform.SetParent(itemsContainer.transform);
    obj.AddComponent<RectTransform>();

    SelectionItem levelViewItem = obj.AddComponent<SelectionItem>();

    GameObject icon = new("icon"); 
    RectTransform iconTransform = icon.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    icon.transform.SetParent(obj.transform);

    SpriteRenderer iconSprite = icon.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    iconSprite.sprite = data[i].Details.LoadIcon(); //Load from disk

    levelViewItem.icon = iconSprite;
    temp[i] = levelViewItem;
}
```

When I run the above code, for the first time, it creates my game objects without an error. However when I update `data` through an event and rebuild the game objects, I get `Not allowed to override geometry on sprite` error and 999+ warnings `Incomplete mesh data in Sprite. Please reimport or recreate Sprite.` It is important to note that I update the SVG files remotely and when the update is complete i rebuild the objects with the new icons stored locally.

If I remove the line
`iconSprite.sprite = data[i].Details.LoadIcon();`

and after the `for` introduce a delay and then apply the sprites the program works as expected, however there is a delay before switching to the new icons which is undesired.

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
foreach (var item in temp)
{
   SpriteRenderer ren = item.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            ren.sprite = books[0].Details.LoadIcon();
}
```

==== SVG Importere ====

```
public static Sprite ProcessSvg(string svgFilePath, string name)
{
     int pixelsPerUnit = 1;
     bool flipYAxis = true;
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(svgFilePath))
     {
         using (StreamReader textReader = File.OpenText(svgFilePath))
         {
              var sceneInfo = SVGParser.ImportSVG(textReader);
              List<Geometry> geometries = TessellateScene(sceneInfo.Scene, new TessellationOptions
              {
                  StepDistance = 1f,
                  SamplingStepSize = 1,
                  MaxCordDeviation = 0,
                  MaxTanAngleDeviation = 0
               });
               Sprite sprite = BuildSprite(geometries, pixelsPerUnit, Alignment.Center, Vector2.zero, 128, flipYAxis);
               prite.name = name;
               return sprite;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       Debug.LogError("SVG content is empty!");
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the implementation of `data[i].Details.LoadIcon()`? What are the relevant types and most importantly what does `LoadIcon` do?

Comment: Also from your usage of `await` ... is this happening on a background thread? Have in mind that most Unity API is only allowed to be sued on the Unity main thread

Comment: @derHugo thanks for your help! The await is a terrible idea here. I just had to narrow down the problem and be sure what is causing it. I've been on this for a few days. Initially I though that the error is at a different part of the program but now I'm sure that it has to do with the building of the objects. I want to replace the await with something that will surely rebuild the new icons without breaking the app.

Comment: What does `BuildSprite` do? please post a [mcve] .. according to things I found online so far this error is quite specific to a `OverrideGeometry` call when happening outside of certain runtime message loops (such as OnGUI, Start, etc)

Comment: `BuildSprite` is part of Unity's Vector Utilities. It is described as - Sprite VectorUtils.BuildSprite(List<Geometry> geoms, float svgPixelsPerUnit, Alignment alignment, Vector2 customPivot, ushort gradientResolution, [bool flipYAxis = false]) (+ 1 overload)
Builds a sprite asset from a scene tessellation.

Returns:
  A new Sprite containing the provided geometry. The Sprite may have a texture if the geometry has any texture and/or gradients.

I also read about the `OverrideGeometry` but couldn't understand much as the information is quite limited and mostly about meshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was that the UI hadn't finished rendering when I was trying to rebuild the gameObject hierarchy. I also had animations reliant on the objects so it was causing the error.

I solved it by waiting for the frame to end before rebuilding the objects.

In the method which called the rebuild function I used a coroutine

```
IEnumerator UpdateData()
{
   yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); // This ensures that the ReloadData() will be called when the frame is rendered;
   EventsManager.Instance.ReloadData();
}
```

This is called by using `StartCoroutine(LibraryUpdated());`

```
void MyCallingMethod()
{
    GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("animationTrigger");
    StartCoroutine(LibraryUpdated());
}
```

Further reading from Unity Docs
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html

I hope this doesn't randomly skip and WaitForEndOfFrame() actually triggers the code every time.

=== ADDITIONAL INSIGHT ===

It turned out, as expected, `WaitForEndOfFrame()` doesn't trigger the code at the right time, which results in the error.

Looks like `yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();` is more reliable. Probably related to the findings by the users on the Unity forum.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/not-allowed-to-override-geometry-on-sprite-error.601882/

Finally, if the `WaitForFixedUpdate()` isn't reliable I'll go for `WaitForSeconds(0.5f)` which, at this point, is similar to making the triggering method `async` and calling `await Task.Delay(500)`